# how should i read a csv file without the 'unnamed' row with pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am writing to a .csv file with:

```
my_data_frame.to_cav("some_path")
```

When trying to read the file with:

```
pd.read_csv("some_path")
```

I can tell that an unnamed column was added.
How can i fix that?

Comment: Can you add sample of `csv`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`to_csv()` writes an index per default, so you can either disable index when saving your CSV:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

or specify an index column when reading:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0)
```

Comment: Ok, that is the solution. Thanks.

Comment: of course, but the site tell me i need to wait several minutes before thah.