# Checking for duplicate data in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange
import os
from os import path
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import sys



while True:
    if path.exists('stockdata.csv') == True:
        data1 = pd.read_csv('stockdata.csv')
        ts = TimeSeries(key='1ORS1XLM1YK1GK9Y', output_format='pandas')
        data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol = 'spy', interval='1min', outputsize='full')
        data = data.rename(columns={'1. open':'Open','2. high': 'High','3. low': 'Low', '4. close':'Close', '5. volume': 'Volume'})
        data1 = data1.append(data)
        data1.to_csv('stockdata.csv', sep= ' ')
        break
    else:
        data1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Open','High','Low', 'Close','Volume'])
        data1.to_csv('stockdata.csv', sep= ' ')
```

What i am trying to do is to check if file `stockdata.csv` is in in the current directory. If it is not found then create the file.

If the file is found then download spy ticker data in `data` and append that data to `data1` and save it in csv file.

The output of data1 looks like this:
[image]

**Problems**

- How do i get rid of `Unnamed:0` column and why is it there?
- How can i check and remove dublicate data in `data` and append that to `data1`?

Comment: Please only ask 1 question per post. All your questions have plenty of duplicates on SO. Please search SO before asking - best way is to use a search engine of your choice and restrict its result to _site:stackoverflow.com_ - ususally any (basic) question you might have is already answered here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you basically have two problems, I will take them both one by one:

#### Problem 1

If you want to get rid of column `Unnamed:0`, you must go for `data1.drop(['Unnamed:0'], axis = 1)`, this will drop the column from the table.

#### Problem 2

Now, if you want to drop the duplicates, you can use `data.drop_duplicates()`, this will drop the duplicate rows and keep the first one intact. After that you can simply `pandas.concat(data1, data)`.

What you basically need is to look for the methods into the pandas documentation, everything is mentioned there bold and clear.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question regarding the added unnamed column: try passing `index=False` or `index_col=0` as per the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977223/how-should-i-read-a-csv-file-without-the-unnamed-row-with-pandas) question on the same topic. 
This forces pandas to read the first column as the index so it doesn't add an additional column.